# Cannot Resolve ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I have a personal project made in python that I worked on and completed in the fall. It used two modules, the 'name' module and the 'pygame' module. I had no issues with simply having

```
import names
import pygame
```

at the top of my code. I was able to run it just fine and present the project for my class. However, after returning to the project after several months, I have found that I get errors like this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'names'
```

I have searched for quite a while and nothing I seem to do changes the issue. Everywhere where I think I might not have the modules downloaded have requirements satisfied, and uninstalling and reinstalling has done nothing. I am still relatively new to the ins and outs of python and I understand that I may have downloaded these modules wrong with pip (or in the wrong spot) or am importing them wrong, but I can't seem to figure out my issue here.

Comment: do you have multiple versions of python installed? can you check via `pip list`  if your module is (e.g. names) installed?